# Marking up Text in an MVVM cross platform scenario

Tags: xamarin, model-view-controller, mvvm, cross-platform

We have an product that uses a shared code base of Models and ViewModels via a PCL, supporting iOS, Android and Windows.

I have examples of string properties from those ViewModels that would benefit from having different parts of the string picked out with different formatting such as bold or Red.

One example is this string that is the number of times a part has been issued. The property in the ViewModel is

> Issued 0 of 5

However sometimes the property need to say

> Final Issue 5 of 5 !Reorder!

Whilst both values are from the IssueState property it might be useful to display the **!Reorder!** in **bold** or perhaps the "5 of 5" with a Foreground of Red.

Another example is a `FoundIn` property of a `SearchResultViewModel` where the value is

> Found In Name, Address and Status

Here we'd want to to bold the "Name", "Address" and "Status" part

> Found In **Name**, **Address** and **Status**

I don't want to split the property up into multiple properties as that is clunky and messes up IMHO the ViewModel

Suggestions for how to solve this? I also don't want to embed too much UI formatting in the ViewModels

My current thinking is to copy iOS SDK's [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring) and it's Range properties for associated "attributes". NSAttributedString is very UI centric so I would allow anywhere near that much formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went for an `AttributedStringViewModel` in the end that held the text as a String and then had a read only property (set in ctor) of a List of `StringFormattingAttribute`

```
public class StringFormattingAttribute
{
    public StringFormattingAttribute(FormattingType type, FormattingRange range)
    {
        this.Type = type;
        this.Range = range;
    }

    public FormattingType Type { get; }

    public FormattingRange Range { get; }
}
```

The `FormattingRange` class hold the start and end position of the string of text that the `StringFormattingAttribute` applies to

In iOS I have an MVVMCross converter to convert to a NSAttributedString